# Loaded XML Document is null (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to load an XML document into Javascript so it can be outputted on a website, however when I load the XML document it is null, and so I get an exception each time I try to read from it. Here is my code:

CODE ON THE WEBPAGE

```
    var xmlDoc;

    loadXML();

    function loadXML(){
        xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("http://www.tomrichardsonweb.co.uk/ABC/xml/pubs.xml");
    }

    function loadPub(){ 
        if(xmlDoc != null){ 
            document.getElementById('pub').innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }else{
            alert("null");
        }
```

loadXMLDoc Method

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
```

}

XML file

```
    < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pub>
    <name>Bay Horse</name>
    <description>Situated at the foot of the stunning Pennine Range, amidst the          breathtaking landscape of Rivington, you will find The Bay Horse Inn. With open fires, cosy corners and a warm friendly atmosphere, this family run inn really does have something for everyone.

The perfect place to relax with family and friends our well stocked bar offers the finest cask ales, refreshing lagers and ciders, quality wines and spirits and a wide selection of soft drinks, teas and coffees.

 For diners our chalkboards boast classic pub food, all freshly prepared and cooked to order, alongside a great range of award winning "Pieminister" pies.

 And for those visiting the area on business or pleasure, or just passing through on a wider journey, and looking for somewhere to rest their heads then our bed and breakfast rooms could be just the answer!  Our friendly team (and our friendly regulars!) will try to make your stay as enjoyable as possible.</description>
    <web>N/a</web>
    <email>N/a</email>
    <phone>N/a</phone>
    <image></image>
</pub>
```

I am constantly getting xmlDoc = null. What is the problem here?

EDIT: In Chrome, under the network tab, it says that the xml document has been loaded. I am testing all this on the server my website is hosted, and not from my machine.

Comment: i tried opening the xml, it contains error, please fix it

Comment: @AnkurMittal This could be the source of the error, however I don't know how to fix it! I have posted the code in my original post.

Comment: here is the fixed xml: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/pubs.xml, just test it

Comment: Don't make your request synchronous, it completely blocks the page.

Comment: @AnkurMittal, Thankyou, I have now managed to fix it. The problem was with my XML file.
It is all working properly now. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: you are welcome:) and as @zippyV said don't use synchronous call, it blocks the page

Comment: @AnkurMittal What do you mean by synchronous call?

Comment: synchronous means your javascript function waits till the xml is downloaded, it can take a lot of time to download on slow net connections so its better to use ajax call like: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/ajax.htm

Comment: @AnkurMittal Thankyou. How can I use that to return the responseXML? I keep getting null every time I try. (I'm sorry for all the questions, I've never really done Javascript!)

Comment: @TomRichardson thats ok, you are still in learning phase, what are you using ajax?(the link i mentioned above) in that case you cannot get null, can you post the code?

Comment: @TomRichardson: If your webpage is not hosted on `www.tomrichardsonweb.co.uk`, it'll never work because cross domain request via *XMLHTTPRequest* is not allowed due to security issue.

Comment: @jay it is hosted on my website when testing.

Comment: @AnkurMittal I cannot post the code right now as I don't have my computer, however I tried replacing the part inside the second if statement to return the responseXML.

Comment: @Ankur - Hi, sorry for the late reply. If possible could you have a look at my code and let me know how I could change it to make it better, as I still do not understand how to do it asynchronously. The page in question is www.tomrichardsonweb.co.uk/ABC/pubs.html  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should move all the inline scripts to the js file so that code is easy to manage, now as for your function

```
function loadPub(i, xml){....}

function loadXMLHTTP(url, callbackfn, args) {//callbackfn:fn you need to load after xml loads, args:argument array to pass to the call back function
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
    alert("No browser support for XML-HTTP-request object")
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        args.push( xmlhttp.responseXML);
        callbackfn.apply(this,args)
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function loadXML(){
        xmlDoc = loadXMLHTTP("xml/pubs.xml",loadPub,[0]);
}
loadXML();
```

In this function the ajax request waits for the xml to load from the server and then it call the function that you pass in it with the args and the xml

Comment: Thankyou, however I am confused as to what I call when a button is pressed to change the text on the page?

Comment: I am also getting "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined. What does this mean?

Comment: You need to call:xmlDoc = loadXMLHTTP("xml/pubs.xml",loadPub,[0]); on button press. you should not get undefined if you are passing [0] as in the code

Comment: Does that mean it redownloads the XML each time? Also, I fixed the push issue. I created an array and added 0 as the first item and passed that it and the push method now works. Is there no way to load the XML and then save it as a variable to be referenced again, or does it need loading each time?

Comment: you can save it if you want to in `loadPub`, you can use a global variable `pubxml`, and assign it the value of `xml`, and then before calling `loadXMLHTTP` just check the value of pubxml; `pubxml==undefined`, this will work till your page doesn't reload, or refresh